Atx psu yellow wire
I have an old 500 watt psu, the yellow cables on the psu box say 12 volts, but with the voltmeter I am testing, it is 6.80 volts!!  Is the psu broken?  Is there any solution for it?  I also tested all the yellow cables and the result was the same

The supply may require a minimum load on the 5V line  in order to supply the proper output on the other lines. Very old supplies frequently do.
You can try a 10Ω 10W ceramic power resistor.
